Proper way to fetch SwiftData models by id
I'm currently working on a simple read operation based on object IDs using SwiftData in my view model. I'm fetching data like this:
func fetch(ids: [String]) {
    var models: [SwiftDataModel] = []
    do {
        let predicate = #Predicate<SwiftDataModel> {
            ids.contains($0.id)
        }
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<SwiftDataModel>(predicate: predicate, sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.title)])
        models = try context.fetch(descriptor)
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}

I'm unsure about the predicate part:
let predicate = #Predicate<SwiftDataModel> {
    ids.contains($0.id)
}

While this seems logical to me, and I am getting correct results, I'm uncertain if it's the correct/efficient approach.
I know there is something like this:
if let model = context.model(for: yourIdGoesHere) as? MyModel {}

but is there something similar for fetching multiple objects by their IDs?
EDIT:
Additionally, while I'm not currently using @Query here, I would be glad to see the same implementation using @Query.

No there isn’t.
